# MySQL: How to select data from a column in another table

Tags: mysql

I have the following select statement:

```
  SELECT
    items.id,
    items.name AS item_name,
    items.tobuy,
    items.list_id,
    items.note,
    items.unit,
    MIN(NULLIF(packages.ppu, 0)) AS mppu,
    packages.price AS mprice,
    items._deleted
  FROM
    items
  INNER JOIN
    lists ON lists.id = items.list_id
  LEFT JOIN
    packages ON items.id = packages.item_id
  WHERE
    lists.user_id = 1 AND
    items._deleted = '0'
  GROUP BY
    items.id
  ORDER BY
    tobuy DESC,
    item_name
```

But what I really want is the price to come from the package that has the minimum ppu (which is not necessarily the package with the minimum price).

Any ideas?

Sample Records:

Table: items:

```
id,  name,  tobuy, list_id, note, unit, _deleted
95,  test1, 1,     1,       null, null, 0
69,  test2, 1,     1,       null, null, 0
194, test3, 1,     1,       null, null, 0
162, test4, 1,     1,       null, null, 0
```

Table: lists:

```
id, name,  user_id
1,  list1, 1
```

Table: packages:

```
id,  item_id, price, ppu
392, 95,      0,     0
117, 95,      13.49, 0.078
391, 95,      0,     0
386, 69,      0,     0
387, 69,      0,     0
388, 69,      0,     0
368, 194,     4.58,  0.138
18,  194,     3.38,  0.177
17,  194,     3.88,  0.144
```

The results should be four items with the following information:

```
id,  item_name,  tobuy, list_id, note, unit, mppu,  mprice, _deleted
95,  test1,      1,     1,       null, null, 0.078, 13.49,  0
69,  test2,      1,     1,       null, null, 0,     0,      0
194, test3,      1,     1,       null, null, 0.138, 4.58,   0
162, test4,      1,     1,       null, null, 0,     0,      0
```

Notice that item 162 doesn't have any corresponding packages, but it still shows up in the list.  This is the reason for the "LEFT JOIN"

BTW, "mppu" stands for "minimum price per unit"

Comment: A side question, why do you use LEFT JOIN instead of the INNER JOIN? It makes your query slower. Also, I'd at least first filtered the lists on user_id and then joined that with the rest.

Comment: please provide sample records with your desired result.

Comment: @Ashalynd, I changed one of the LEFT JOIN statements to an INNER JOIN, but I can't change the other one because I still need to list the items that don't have any corresponding data in the packages table.

Comment: @491243, I added sample records and the desired result for these four types of situations.  Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works to get the results that I was looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM (  
  SELECT
    items.id,
    items.name AS item_name,
    items.tobuy,
    items.list_id,
    items.note,
    items.unit,
    NULLIF(packages.ppu, 0) AS mppu,
    packages.price AS mprice,
    items._deleted
  FROM
    items
  INNER JOIN
    lists ON lists.id = items.list_id
    AND lists.user_id = 1 
  LEFT JOIN
    packages ON packages.item_id = items.id
  WHERE
    items._deleted = '0'
  ORDER BY
    tobuy DESC,
    item_name,
    IFNULL(mppu, 999999)) x
GROUP BY
  x.id
ORDER BY
  tobuy DESC,
  item_name
```

Thanks to everyone for the input to get me through this.

Answer (score 0):

can you try for the 2nd left:
    `packages ON ( packages.item_id = items.id and select min(packages.ppu) from packages where item_id=item.id)`

also make sure to change group by to items.id
not tested

Comment: I replaced my LEFT JOIN with the following 
`LEFT JOIN
    packages ON ( packages.item_id = items.id and 
                 select min(packages.ppu) 
                 from packages 
                 where packages.item_id=items.id )`
but that returns a syntax error in the select line ??

Comment: maybe i'm missing something, it's not tested
i guess, i misspelled packages two times,

Comment: I corrected the misspellings (as you can see in my previous post).  What do you mean by "it's not tested"?

Comment: He means he didn't bother creating your schema, adding data and testing the query. Neither would I.

Comment: ok, actually just remove the select keep `packages ON packages.item_id = items.id` it's just flipped

Comment: removing the select and swapping `items.id = packages.item_id` to `packages.item_id = items.id` behaves the same as my original code.  The price is still not coming from the row with the MIN mppu.

Answer (score 0):

With mysql this is surprisingly simplex.

Order by ppn and move the group by to an outer query

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    items.id,
    items.name AS item_name,
    items.tobuy,
    items.list_id,
    items.note,
    items.unit,
    MIN(NULLIF(packages.ppu, 0)) AS mppu,
    packages.price AS mprice,
    items._deleted
  FROM items
  INNER JOIN lists
    ON lists.id = items.list_id
    AND lists.user_id = 1
  LEFT JOIN packages
    ON items.id = packages.item_id
  WHERE items._deleted = '0'
  ORDER BY
    ppm,
    tobuy DESC,
    item_name) x
GROUP BY
  id
```

Comment: I changed the typo in the ORDER BY section from ppm to mppu, but this code only returns a single item.

Comment: I did manage to get this method to produce the desirable results by 
1) removing the `MIN`
2) adding the `ORDER BY tobuy DESC, item_name` again after the `GROUP BY` statement and
3) changing the first `ORDER BY` to `IFNULL(mppu, 999999)`

but this query is slow.  Any suggestions on speeding this up?

Comment: Move the non-key condition on lists from the WHERE into the join ON - see edit. Note:I have not yet incorporated your other changes.

Comment: What is the significance of moving the non-key condition as you suggest?  Both ways seem to produce the desired result.

Comment: @simpler it means the condition gets executed as the join occurs, before the subsequent join to `packages`, which should savour lots of work. Leaving it in the where clause means it executes as a filter on the rowset *after* all joins are made. Note that the optimizer msg do this itself anyway.